# Python saving a list of strings for later export

Tags: python, list

I am using Python 3.12.

```
str = ("\nsetV\t Current\t Meas V")
print (str)
results = [str]
```

I have the following is a loop:

```
print(f'{volts:.3f}\t',current.rstrip()," \t",f'{Meas_Volts:.3f}')
str = (f'{volts:.3f}\t',current.rstrip()," \t",f'{Meas_Volts:.3f}')
results.append (str)
```

It prints a set of three measurements a line at a time and saves to a list for use later.

When the loop finishes, do a print of the list to test for later saving to a file.

```
print(*results, sep='\n')
```

The Output is:

```
setV     Current     Meas V
1.000    -0.002      0.831
2.000    0.001       1.998
3.000    0.001       2.999
4.000    0.001       4.001
5.000    0.001       5.002

setV     Current     Meas V
('1.000\t', '-0.002', ' \t', '0.831')
('2.000\t', '0.001', ' \t', '1.998')
('3.000\t', '0.001', ' \t', '2.999')
('4.000\t', '0.001', ' \t', '4.001')
('5.000\t', '0.001', ' \t', '5.002')
```

I want the list's output to look like the first set of outputs and later save to a text file.

Comment: Side note: don't use `str` as a variable name. That shadows the builtin `str`

Comment: Thanks,  I revised that. to use "string"

Answer (score 0):

You can print (and save as str) the variables as one whole string similar to what you did with the first variable, but extended:

```
a = 1.000
b = -0.002
c = 0.831
print("setV\tCurrent\tMeas V")
print(f'{a:.3f}\t{b:.3f}\t{c:.3f}')
```

Output:

```
setV    Current Meas V
1.000   -0.002  0.831
```

Comment: Not sure how that helps.  That is exactly what I am doing for each loop iteration, printing a string as a line.  I need to store each string in a list and then later print the whole list to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that works. Inside the loop just after the print statement, string = .join(same as for print .
Inside the loop:

```
print(f'{volts:.3f}\t',f'{current:.3f}\t',f'{Meas_Volts:.3f}')
string = ''.join((f'{volts:.3f}\t',f'{current:.3f}\t',f'{Meas_Volts:.3f}')) 
results.append (string)
```

After the loop:

```
print(*results, sep='\n')
```

Output:
Enter the start value: 1
Enter the stop value: 10
Enter the step value: 1

setV     Current Meas V
1.000    -0.002  0.946
2.000    0.001   1.998
3.000    0.001   2.999
4.000    0.001   4.001
5.000    0.001   5.002
6.000    0.001   6.003
7.000    0.001   7.004
8.000    0.001   7.997
9.000    0.001   8.998
10.000   0.001   9.999

setV     Current Meas V
1.000   -0.002  0.946
2.000   0.001   1.998
3.000   0.001   2.999
4.000   0.001   4.001
5.000   0.001   5.002
6.000   0.001   6.003
7.000   0.001   7.004
8.000   0.001   7.997
9.000   0.001   8.998
10.000  0.001   9.999

Press Q to exit

Comment: The output did not format the columns in this post but it dose on my screen.